# table#t01 vs table#01 in HTML

Tags: css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  table#t01 td,tr,th { border:1px dotted red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="t01">
    <tr> <th> Monthy <th>Saving
    <tr> <th> Jan    <td>100
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't get why if I change `t01` to `01`, the code won't work. I thought `id` can be numbers too.

Also, does it make a difference if I write `table#t01 td,tr,th {}`, instead of writing it separately like `table#t01 td{}` `table#t01 tr{}`. I am pretty new to programming.

Comment: Did you change `t01` in both the html and the style?  Also what do you mean by not work, does the style not get applied, do you get an error message?  Do the styles applied look correct if viewed in the developer tools via the F12 key?

Comment: You should explain where exactly you're changing t01 to 01 and provide an example of the "broken" code.

Comment: Yes I changed `t01` to `01` in both style and html, and the style (border) won't apply. I think Paige gave me the answer, that IDs simply can't start with a number. Thanks!

Comment: Then can you mark mine as correct :)

Answer (score 3):

An ID can contain numbers, but it cannot start with a number. From [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) stating that " In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit** "